# How to cast to MyInterface<TEntity>

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have implemented a generic repository, but have a requirement to dynamically create the appropriate repository at runtime given the entity type as a string.

I have managed to create the repository using:

```
        Assembly common = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"CommonLibrary.dll");
        Type entityType = common.GetType("Models.OneOfManyEntities");
        Type repoType = typeof(TradeSiftRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

        var repo = Activator.CreateInstance(repoType, new UnitOfWork());
```

However `repo` is an object and I really want it cast to `IRepository<TEntity>` I have tried `IRepository<entityType>` but that is not correct

This is the interface for the repo:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll();
    IQueryable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");
    TEntity FindById(object Id);
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

The activated instance of the repo is of the correct type, but Activator returns a object type so I need to cast it to use the methods.

Comment: What type do you get if you use `repo.GetType()`?

Comment: The created instance of the repo is of the correct type, but I have to cast it to use the methods, for example repo.FindById(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking is possible. If your code is receiving a string that represents the generic type parameter, the type it represents can only be determined at runtime. However, generic type parameters should be specified at compile time.

I think you'll have to instead receive the type of entity as a generic type parameter if you want to use it as a type parameter of the return type:

```
public IRepository<TEntity> MakeRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    var repo = new TradeSiftRepository<TEntity>(new UnitOfWork());
    return repo;
}

IRepository<User> userRepository = MakeRepository<User>();
```

If you definitely want to receive the entity type name as a string, the responsibility of casting the result to the real type at compile time should be done by calling code, since the calling code is what specifies the type:

```
public object MakeRepository(string entityTypeName)
{
    Assembly common = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"CommonLibrary.dll");
    Type entityType = common.GetType(entityTypeName);
    Type repoType = typeof(TradeSiftRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

    var repo = Activator.CreateInstance(repoType, new UnitOfWork());
    return repo;
}

IRepository<User> userRepository = (IRepository<User>)MakeRepository("User");
```

However, the above code can be simplified by using the generic version of the method; there is less duplication. If the calling code also doesn't know what type it's asking for, I think you're out of options.

One possible work-around is to return the dynamic type, which would leave the calling code to assume it has an object of the type its author wants:

```
public dynamic MakeRepository(string entityTypeName)
{
    Assembly common = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"CommonLibrary.dll");
    Type entityType = common.GetType(entityTypeName);
    Type repoType = typeof(TradeSiftRepository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

    var repo = Activator.CreateInstance(repoType, new UnitOfWork());
    return repo;
}

dynamic userRepository = MakeRepository("ConsoleApplication1.User");
User user = userRepository.FindById(1);
```

Comment: I think the requirement does indeed make sense; I have come across such situations myself - every time lists/graphs are handled in a certain way, while the entity type is determined only later on. The only part that doesn't work out yet is the separation between code that needs to know the entity type and code that doesn't. See my solution #2 that moves the boundary between those two sections of code to a more meaningful place.

Comment: I just re-read the question, and I noticed that casting the result to the correct type was not part of the requirement, so I think you're right. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, yes "dynamic" does the trick, I didn't need to cast the repository to the correct type and the entities returned by each repository all conform to the same interface.

Comment: @HadleyHope: Be aware that the `dynamic` keyword is much like disabling any compile-time type checking. i.e. errors due to invalid calls might get apparent only during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to cast the object to `IRepository<TEntity>`, but `TEntity` is only available at runtime (you have a reference to the `Type` object in the `entityType` variable).

If `IRepository<entityType>` were possible, what would you expect to get back from methods such as `FindById`? Probably an `entityType` instance, I presume? Now, as `entityType` could be any type and is only determined at runtime, the compiler cannot possibly know how to compile any code involving `entityType` variables. Therefore, `IRepository<entityType>` is not possible.

There are two possible solutions, depending on what you want to achieve:

1. If you do not want to run any code that needs to know about your entity objects, implement an additional `IRepository`-like interface that handles entities of type `object` (and possibly throws `ArgumentException`s if anything is added that does not match the current `entityType`). Cast the result of your `Activator.CreateInstance` call to that new interface type.
2. Create a new generic class that takes the entity type as a generic argument. Move all the code that deals with your entities and repositories into that new class, where it always uses the entity type supplied as a generic argument. Instantiate that generic class via `Activator.CreateInstance` similarly to what you're doing now directly with the `TradeSiftRepository<T>` class.

Comment: Yes I would expect back an entityType instance.  In this particular case all the entities would implement a specific interface.

Comment: @HadleyHope: The compiler cannot possibly know that, as `entityType` can be anything. You could implement my solution #1 with your entity interface type rather than `object`, however. (Of course, solution #2 works as described, and you can provide your entity interface as a generic constraint.)